# PHP Mail form with Ajax validation not working

Tags: php, ajax, validation

I am using a simple HTML form with an ajax validation, and php to mail, however It keeps giving me the error that the message was not sent. If I disable the ajax the form will go through. What can I do to fix this issue?

HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/tj/send.php">
                                                    <p>
                                                        <label for="name">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <label for="subject">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                                        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
                                                    </p>
                                                    <div class="fBtn">
                                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="regButton"><i class="icon-paper-plane"></i>Send Message</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                            <div id="success"><h2>Your message has been sent. Thank you!</h2></div>
                        <div id="error"><h2>Sorry your message can not be sent.</h2></div>
                                        </div>
```

AJAX Validation:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){ 

$('input#name').removeClass("errorForm");
$('textarea#message').removeClass("errorForm");
$('input#email').removeClass("errorForm");

var error = false; 
var name = $('input#name').val(); 
if(name == "" || name == " ") { 
    error = true; 
    $('input#name').addClass("errorForm");
}


    var msg = $('textarea#message').val(); 
    if(msg == "" || msg == " ") {
        error = true;
        $('textarea#message').addClass("errorForm");
        
    }

var email_compare = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i; 
var email = $('input#email').val(); 
if (email == "" || email == " ") { 
    $('input#email').addClass("errorForm");
    error = true;
}else if (!email_compare.test(email)) { 
    $('input#email').addClass("errorForm");
    error = true;
}

if(error == true) {
    return false;
}

var data_string = $('.contactForm form').serialize(); 


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $('.contactForm form').attr('action'),
    data: data_string,
    
    success: function(message) {
                console.log("AJAX Error:" + message);
            if(message == 'SENDING'){
                $('#success').fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else{

                $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
            }
                }
                
                
                
});

return false; 
});
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
/* Code by David McKeown - craftedbydavid.com */
/* Editable entries are bellow */
$send_to = "bob@gmail.com";
$send_subject = "bob.net form";

/*Be careful when editing below this line */
$name = cleanupentries($_POST["name"]);
$email = cleanupentries($_POST["email"]);
$subject = cleanupentries($_POST["subject"]);
$message = cleanupentries($_POST["message"]);
$from_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$from_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];



function cleanupentries($entry) {
    $entry = trim($entry);
    $entry = stripslashes($entry);
    $entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);
    return $entry;
}
$message = "This email was submitted on " . date('m-d-Y') . 
"\n\nName: " . $name .
"\n\nE-Mail: " . $email . 
"\n\nMessage: \n" . $message . 
"\n\n\nTechnical Details:\n" . $from_ip . "\n" . $from_browser;
$send_subject .= " - {$name}";
$headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($send_to,$send_subject,$message);
?>
```

Edit: Updated to remove personal information from code.

Comment: In your php, you set up all those variables, but i never see the `mail()` function called...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like 2 separate problems. The form submission, and the email actually sending.

I can speak to php failing in sending email.  (sorry castis I didn't see your comment until after I submitted my answer).

There should be more code there, perhaps using the php `mail` command (with parameters), or for even better chances of the recipient actually getting the email, use an SMTP mail, typically set up by server admin.

Also, try console.log(message), just above the line `if (message == 'SENDING')`.

Also, in what part of the code is any value the string 'SENDING'? Your `if` statement may just be evaluating to false for that reason alone.

As you mentioned in comment, the output of your console.log of line 111 was `AJAX Error: script.js:111`
This is indicating that message is empty, nothing. Hence, your if statement 
if (message == 'SENDING') will indeed evaluate to false.
I would try revising your code so as to have 2 callbacks, success and error.

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#success').fadeIn('slow');
},
error: function(xhr) {
  $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

For more info, I found this useful: http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-post/

Comment: Okay I've added the mail command: `mail($send_to, $send_subject,$name,$email,$subject,$message,$headers);`, however i still receive the ajax error and I still do not recieve the email.

Comment: Getting the mail to actually get to someone using the php mail function is hit-and-miss. Check this out. http://www.jvfconsulting.com/blog/190/PHP_Mail_Function_vs_SMTP_Guaranteed_Delivery.html

Comment: Okay I will add console.log inside the AJAX success message.. Also, I changed my mail command to `mail($send_to,send_subject,$message);` and it send the email correctly, but still the ajax error.

Comment: the console.log is not bringing up any errors. I don't understand what you mean for the value of 'SENDING' -- is it supposed to be something else? Also, I updated my code on the original post.

Comment: `AJAX Error: script.js:111 ` -- I locate line 111, and its the console.log line. will it help if you just view the site itself?